# Crontab expression for WAS Scheduler

Tags: websphere, cron, scheduler

I have to Schedule a job with next conditions:

- every hour from 19:00 to 20:00 (so, 2 times)
- every day from 27-30 of every month
- if one of the days is Saturday or Sunday the job should not run.

My actual expression works like this:

    1.Monday, April 27, 2015 7:00 PM
    2.Monday, April 27, 2015 8:00 PM
    3.Tuesday, April 28, 2015 7:00 PM
    4.Tuesday, April 28, 2015 8:00 PM
    5.Wednesday, April 29, 2015 7:00 PM
    6.Wednesday, April 29, 2015 8:00 PM
    7.Thursday, April 30, 2015 7:00 PM
    8.Thursday, April 30, 2015 8:00 PM
    9.Wednesday, May 27, 2015 7:00 PM
    10.Wednesday, May 27, 2015 8:00 PM
    11.Thursday, May 28, 2015 7:00 PM
    12.Thursday, May 28, 2015 8:00 PM
    13.Friday, May 29, 2015 7:00 PM
    14.Friday, May 29, 2015 8:00 PM
    <s>15.Saturday, May 30, 2015 7:00 PM</s>
    <s>16.Saturday, May 30, 2015 8:00 PM</s>
    <s>17.Saturday, June 27, 2015 7:00 PM</s>
    <s>18.Saturday, June 27, 2015 8:00 PM</s>
    <s>19.Sunday, June 28, 2015 7:00 PM</s>
    <s>20.Sunday, June 28, 2015 8:00 PM</s>

But I need to run just in weekdays. There is a way to modify my crontab expression to avoid this situation?

My crontab expression:

```
0 0/60 19-20 27-30 1/1 ? *
```

I created my crontab expression with [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

If you need more information please leave a comment. Thank you very much!

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your crontab is rather ambivalent,

```
0 0/60 19-20 27-30 1/1 ? *
```

It is supposed to follow this format:

```
m h dom mon dow command
```

However, if your first zero, the star and question mark is ignored, and the `dow` field is set to 1-5 (Monday through Friday), one gets:

```
0 19-20 27-30 1 1-5 [cmd]
```

which I think would work for your application.

Comment: That's the reason I send you to that website. :) Because I need a cron expression for WAS Scheduler.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as such. Cheers!